# certificatePinner not working with okhttp throwing SSLHandshakeException: CertPathValidatorException Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, okhttp

I've taken the code from [Square's own github Readme:](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS#customizing-trusted-certificates)

```
 @Throws(Exception::class)
 fun run() {
      val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .certificatePinner(CertificatePinner.Builder()
                          .add("api.somewebsite.nl", "sha256/SOME_KEY/SOME_KEY")
                          .build())
                .build()

      val request = Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.somewebsite.nl")
                .build()

      try {
           val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
           if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.i("TestCode","is Not Successful")
                throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")
           } else {
                Log.i("TestCode","is Successful")
           }

           for (certificate in response.handshake()!!.peerCertificates()) {
                println(CertificatePinner.pin(certificate))
           }

      } catch (e: SSLHandshakeException) {
           e.printStackTrace()
      }
 }
```

When going to this website using Chrome it works, indicating that the App has the Comodo CA certificate on the particular phone. For the SHA256 pin value I went [to this site](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=somewebsite.nl&latest). This site is also mentioned in [this excellent walkthrough](https://medium.com/@krisnavneet/certificate-pinning-in-retrofit-android-using-certificatepinner-8506c5be117e).

I've used the latest versions of the libraries:

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.5.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1"
```

Here is the Logging:

```
 E/Conscrypt: ------------------Untrusted chain: ----------------------
 E/Conscrypt: == Chain0 == 
     Version:   3
 E/Conscrypt:  Serial Number:   serial_number
 E/Conscrypt:  SubjectDN:   CN=*.somewebsite.nl, OU=PremiumSSL Wildcard, OU=IT, O=somewebsite B.V., STREET=some_street, L=SomeCity, ST=SomeCity, OID.2.5.4.17=POSTAL_CODE, C=NL
 E/Conscrypt:  IssuerDN:   CN=Sectigo RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA, O=Sectigo Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
 E/Conscrypt:  Get not before:   Mon May 06 02:00:00 GMT+02:00 2019
 E/Conscrypt:  Get not after:   Mon Jul 05 01:59:59 GMT+02:00 2021
 E/Conscrypt:  Sig ALG name:   SHA256withRSA
 E/Conscrypt:  Signature:   SOME_SIGNATURE
 E/Conscrypt:  Public key:

 W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
 W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:361)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:336)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:300)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:185)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:107)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:87)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:221)
 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Have you found solution @jim clermonts

Answer (score -3):

Try to Modify OkHttpClient.Builder Object: see [this](https://mobikul.com/android-retrofit-handling-sslhandshakeexception/) solution

Comment: The man is trying to pin a certificate, but you suggest disabling certificate checking o_O